# Installing Android SDK and ADT in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I am trying to start Android Development and trying to do so using the ADT plugin in my Eclipse Mars(Windows 10)

I have installed the ADT plugin in my eclipse version 23.0.7.2120684.

Also I have downloaded the SDK tools(tools_r25.2.3-windows) and extracted it to D:/eclipse\SDK.

But everytime I open Eclipse and click on Windows->Preferences ->and enter the SDK Location as D:/eclipse\SDK which is the SDK folder I am getting the below error:

The Android SDK requires the new Build Tools component to be installed.

Please open the SDK Manager and install "Android SDK Build-tools"

I click on Open SDK Manager and nothing happens, but I get an error message in the console:

[2017-04-10 22:56:35 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Error: Expected verb after global parameters but found 'sdk' instead.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong here. Most of the installation guides/steps found on the net are a bit redundant since they are quite old.

Comment: As far as I know, the ADT plugin is no longer actively supported or maintained, you need to be using Android Studio.

Comment: Why do you want to setup Android SDK in Eclipse? Android dropped the support for Eclipse some time ago. Install official Android Studio.

Comment: My guess is that you will need to use an older Android SDK, in the 23.x or 24.x series. Or, see if [Andmore](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.andmore) is ready for use. Or, as others have suggested, use a better-supported IDE (Android Studio, or perhaps IntelliJ IDEA).

Answer (score 4):

As of Android SDK Tools Revision 25.3.0 removes obsolete/deprecated tools, see [Release Notes](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidsdktoolsrevision2530feb2017), and as ADT plugin is no longer supported it cannot work with it.

However revision 25.2.3 should be working. If you still want to use Eclipse try to look at [Eclipse Neon for Android Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-android-developers-includes-incubating-components/neon3).

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse no longer supports Android Application Development. [Announcement here.](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

You might install Android Studio or Intellij Idea to create android apps using java.

Comment: This is a comment at best. Even then you're not adding anything that isn't already there.

Comment: @takendarkk Low reputation here, sorry.

Comment: So edit some posts or write real answers to get some rep.

Comment: Are you guys serious..so the good old days of developing android in eclipse are over ?

Comment: @user1741642 yeah, there's been a lot of time since they announced it.

Comment: You have that backwards. Android no longer supports Eclipse.